# syntax error near unexpected character fi

Tags: bash

Im testing for versions of various things installed on my linux distro, but I keep getting this error

```
cat > version-check.sh << "EOF"
#!/bin/bash
# Simple script to list version numbers of critical development tools
export LC_ALL=C
bash --version | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f2-4
MYSH=$(readlink -f /bin/sh)
echo "/bin/sh -> $MYSH"
echo $MYSH | grep -q bash || echo "ERROR: /bin/sh does not point to bash"
unset MYSH
echo -n "Binutils: "; ld --version | head -n1 | cut -d" " -f3-
bison --version | head -n1
if [ -h /usr/bin/yacc ]; then
 echo "/usr/bin/yacc -> `readlink -f /usr/bin/yacc`";
elif [ -x /usr/bin/yacc ]; then
 echo yacc is `/usr/bin/yacc --version | head -n1`
else
 echo "yacc not found"
fi
EOF
```

At the end of this file I get the syntax error.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You don't have a terminating `EOF` for your here doc

Comment: Running with `bash -x yourscript` and inspecting the logs might be a useful place to start -- if there are stray `$'\r'`s that means you've got DOS newlines, and that would explain the bug. (BTW, if you need `/bin/sh` to point to `/bin/bash`, that's probably not a good thing -- it means you have scripts using `#!/bin/sh` shebangs that **should** be using `#!/bin/bash` shebangs instead, or else they'd work with a more minimal shell like dash as `/bin/sh`; only POSIX-compliant scripts should use `#!/bin/sh`).

Comment: I don't have `yacc` on my host and this script runs ok as is which makes me suspect the two `echo` statements. Try quoting the args of the `echo` command in `elif` so it looks like this:

    echo "yacc is `/usr/bin/yacc --version | head -n1`"

Comment: gack - I hate trying to put code in comments. There should be some backticks in there. The same line as you had, just with double quotes around the all the args.

Comment: Charles Duffy `bash -x version-check.sh 
+ export LC_ALL=C
+ LC_ALL=C
+ cut '-d ' -f2-4
+ head -n1
+ bash --version
bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release
++ readlink -f /bin/sh
+ MYSH=/bin/bash
+ echo '/bin/sh -> /bin/bash'
/bin/sh -> /bin/bash
+ grep -q bash
+ echo /bin/bash
+ unset MYSH
+ echo -n 'Binutils: '
Binutils: + cut '-d ' -f3-
+ head -n1
+ ld --version
(GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30
+ head -n1
+ bison --version
bison (GNU Bison) 3.0.4
version-check.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
version-check.sh: line 19: `fi'`

Comment: The script emitted by your command passes [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) with a small number of warnings, and runs on my system without producing the error you describe.  I'm inclined to suspect that the issue is related to failure to quote the result of the command substitution `/usr/bin/yacc --version | head -n1`, which is in fact the most significant issue shellcheck raised, but it is not immediately obvious to me why that might lead to your error.